# Get all the combinations between arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, combinations, slice

I have this code that is trying to return an array with all the combinations that can be possible between two or more arrays.
But I have this issue.

```
getCombn(arr: string | any[], pre?: string | undefined) {
    pre = pre || ' ';
    if (!arr.length) {
      return pre;
    }
    var ans = arr[0].reduce(function (ans: string | any[], value: string | any) {
      return ans.concat(getCombn(arr.slice(1), pre + value));}
      
      , []);

    this.uesa.innerHTML = arr;
    
    return ans;
  }
```

"Cannot find name 'getCombn'."

¿What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should include the entire class in your example, otherwise it is not a working MRE.

Answer (score 1):

looks like you forgot to add `this` when you call your function recursively.

try modifying your line `return ans.concat(getCombn(arr.slice(1), pre + value));}`

to `return ans.concat(this.getCombn(arr.slice(1), pre + value));}`